# Make text transition smoothly

Tags: css, css-transitions

Hey I'm building my site and I have a problem.

Here is my site: http://legacybydesign.tv/webdesign/index.html

When you take over the menu it expends. But the text jumps and I wonder if you can make it more smooth?

Comment: please include code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to add the transition to your hover state and also animate the line-height and background.
I would also recommend changing your speed to .3s

```
.inactive:{
    height: 5.083em;
    line-height: 5.083em;
    padding: 0 2.618em 0 1.618em;
    border-bottom: 0.09em solid rgba(255, 234, 173, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease, line-height .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease, line-height .5s ease;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease, line-height .5s ease;
    transition: height .3s ease, line-height .5s ease;
}

.inactive:hover{
    background-color: #ca0012;
    height: 6.853em;
    line-height: 6.853em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're animating only on the `height` property, but you're changing the line-height also. Try changing the `animation` property on `.inactive` to this:

```
transition: height 0.5s ease-out, line-height 0.5s ease-out; 
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-out, line-height 0.5s ease-out;
```

Answer (score 0):

apply `ease-in-out` on H2 and class inactive

```
.inactive {
height: 5.083em;
line-height: 5.083em;
padding: 0 2.618em 0 1.618em;
border-bottom: 0.09em solid rgba(255, 234, 173, 0.1);
transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.inactive h2 {
color: white;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: right;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```